# В таком ССП, без подлежащего, запятая не ставится?

Tags: пунктуация

> В таких залах ведут переговоры, пируют или ожидают высокопоставленное
>   лицо и здесь могут прежде ознакомиться с размышлениями хозяина по
>   разным поводам, которые непременно приведут к философской беседе
>   достойные умы.

Потому что *пируют, ожидают* и *могут*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Розенталя в  неопределенно-личных предложениях **запятая не ставится**, **если мыслится один производитель действия.** Здесь этим производителем, вероятно, являются различные посетители.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

Comment: Жасминчик, сразу вручить ЛОшку мне помешали дурацкие примеры после гиперссылки, - давай их уберём? Оне ж такие прозрачные, что с моим случаем, где соприсутствуют  *в таких залах* и *здесь*, гипотетически могущих на что-то влиять, рядом не лежали. Убери своей лапкой избыточное, а?

Answer (score 1):

Ведут, пируют и ожидают — "в таких залах", а могут ознакомиться — "здесь". В полном предложении такой структуры подлежащее повторялось бы. Это скорее ССП, чем просто однородные сказуемые, и запятая нужна.

Comment: Проблема в том, что у нас подразумевается общее подлежащее. В растерянности мы.

Comment: На мой взгляд, подлежащее подразумевается не общее, а повторяющееся.

Comment: М_Г, я уже жаловалась на себя, что не сильна в терминологии. Жасмин чётко обозначила сей феномен: неопределенно-личные предложения. Со своими законами.

Comment: Я рассуждаю так. Поставим туда подлежащее "они". Чтобы фраза зазвучала, нужно повторить его дважды: *В таких залах они ведут переговоры, пируют или ожидают высокопоставленное лицо, и здесь (же) они могут прежде ознакомиться с размышлениями хозяина по разным поводам.* Запятая оправдана!

Comment: Из правила: *Не забываем, что однородные подлежащие и сказуемые создают НЕ сложное, а простое осложнённое предложение*, - я в этом не смыслю.

Comment: *Они делают то, и здесь же они делают это* -  тут нет однородных подлежащих, тут два предложения.